# ScrollView to the left of the screen in qml

Tags: qt, listview, qml, scrollview

I am trying to put scrollview to the leftside of a ListView in qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item {

    width: 1580 
    height: 687 

    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "Gray"
    }

    ListModel
    {
        id: phonecontactsModel

        ListElement {
            // name :firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Alexander"
            lastname:"Wurz"
            contactimg: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: ""
            phonenum:"02476 000 001"
            favstatus:0
        }

        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
        ListElement{
            //name:firstname+" "+lastname
            firstname:"Bernie"
            lastname:"Ecclestone"
            contactimg:"graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            contactimgSq: "graphics/Phone/contacts/contact_pic1.png"
            phonenum:"02476 000 002"
            favstatus:1
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        id: id_scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent
        objectName: "ScrollView"
        frameVisible: true
        highlightOnFocus: true
    ListView
    {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        model: phonecontactsModel
        delegate: contacts_delegate
        spacing: 6 
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 360 
        clip: true

    }
}


    Component
    {
        id: contacts_delegate

        Item {
            id: wrapper
            height: 150 
            width: 1080 

            Rectangle
            {
                color: "#99000000"
                height: parent.height
                width: parent.width -150
            }


            Image {
                width: parent.height
                height: parent.height
                id: contactImage
                source: contactimg
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                anchors.left: parent.left
            }

            Text {
                id: contactName
                text: firstname
                anchors.left: contactImage.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 70  
                color: "White"
                font.pointSize: 25  
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Image {
                id: messageContact
                source: "graphics/Phone/messaging_icon.png"
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }



        }
    }
}
```

I cannot specify the scrollview width or height or the position it to the left of the view how can i achieve this

I am trying to create something like this

[image: I am trying to create this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what I guess is right, you can use the `QtQuick.Controls 2.0 ScrollBar` instead of using a scrollview.

e.g:

```
ListView {
    id: lview
    anchors.right: parent.right
    width: 300
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    model: 100
    delegate: Rectangle { width: 300; height: 50; border.color: 'grey' }
    spacing: 6

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        anchors.right: lview.left
        width: 50
        active: true
        background: Item {
            Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                height: parent.height
                width: parent.width * 0.2
                color: 'grey'
                radius: width / 2
            }
        }

        contentItem: Rectangle {
            radius: width / 3
            color: 'yellow'
        }
    }
}
```

You can customize this ScrollBar to your liking.
See here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollbar

Comment: did this worked for you?i cant see the scrollbar while i try like this

Comment: You probably still clip the ListView, while I placed the ScrollBar just outside the ListView - therefore you clip the scrollbar. Or you just don't like the basic style... That fades away automatically.

Comment: yes i can see them now!! How can i clip the listview now? I tried clipping the scrollbar? no effect

Comment: You could for example wrap the whole thing in an `Item` that you then clip.

Comment: Another way to fix the clipping is, to move the ScrollBar to be a sibling to the `ListView`, and just set the `ScrollBar.vertical: idOfTheScrollbar`. Then you should be able to set the `ListView` to clip as you used to.

Comment: I will give it a try? While trying to customize the scrollbar is there any way to tell that the contentItem width to be grater than the background. Like the yellow indicator in the image which is larger than the scrollBar background

Comment: setting clipping to false does not allow the rectangle to come outside.... no matter what it always stay inside the background

Comment: I have added an image in the question, there you could see the yellow indicator width is larger than the backgraound(grey line) In our example, whenever i try to increase the width of the contentItem{blue rectangle} it does not grow, it clips off at the background rectangle's width {it always stays inside the rectangle}.. any way we could design like in the image

Comment: As an advice, just mark comments as "obsolete" or "chatty" once you have settlled the argumentation. Thanks. :)